# What is Hadoop linuxexecutorcontainer exit code 15

Tags: java, scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hortonworks-data-platform

When running a Spark job, I see the following error message in Yarn node manager logs -

```
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.LinuxContainerExecutor: Exit code from container container_e434_2334234233423_0001_01_000001 is : 15
```

Any idea what that error code means?

Comment: it could be `#define ENOTBLK         15      /* Block device required */`

Comment: Never figured out what that was. We did a fresh install of the cluster and never saw that error again.